# Eclipse formatter: how do I align the code in my method

Tags: java, eclipse, formatter

ctrl+shift+F work fine for what is inside the public class .
but the formatting does not work inside the method, see the = sign is not aligned. why? and how do I get this to work?

```
public class myClass extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 {
    public static boolean       myVar                            = true;
    private static final String TARGET_PACKAGE_ID                = "com.xxxx.test";
    private static final String LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_FULL_CLASSNAME = "com.xxxx.test";
    private static Class        launcherActivityClass;

...
...
private String getOnScreeninfoByType() {
        ArrayList<TextView> textViews = new ArrayList<TextView>();
        ArrayList<Button> listButtons = new ArrayList<Button>();
        ArrayList<ToggleButton> listToggleButtons = new ArrayList<ToggleButton>();
        ArrayList<EditText> listEditTexts = new ArrayList<EditText>();
        ArrayList<CheckBox> listCheckBoxes = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();
        ArrayList<RadioButton> listRadioButtons = new ArrayList<RadioButton>();
        ArrayList<ImageButton> listImageButtons = new ArrayList<ImageButton>();
        ArrayList<ImageView> listImageViews = new ArrayList<ImageView>();
        ArrayList<ProgressBar> listProgressBars = new ArrayList<ProgressBar>();
...

    }
```

thanks

Answer (score 5):

There is an option `Align Fields in Columns` in `Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter > Edit > Indentation`. If this option is checked, fields in class are aligned as you saw. However, I couldn't find any options `Align Local Variables` or something like that. It seems that there is no option to align local variables in columns.

Comment: Same here, couldn't find anything that would align within a method.

Answer (score 1):

They are not aligned because they should not be aligned!
The special alignment in the class, could be caused by a special non standard formating rule, that was set up by the person which created that project.
Look in project settings in eclipse under Code Formatter (or simillar)

Comment: why should they not be aligned? I mean, would the code be nicer and easier to read?

Comment: no it is not. in nested loops this would cause line length greater than 100. nor is this not possible. code is complexer than variable declarations

Comment: I have just few nested loops in my code, also since some programmers have 22'+ displays the line length of more than 100 is not really a problem.

Comment: @dit You easily exceed the 120 limit even without alignment. so aliging local variables is just a bad idea.

Comment: @AlexWien my limit now is 300. and i'm aligning local variables very often, (by using formatter:off). so you can not tell us it is a bad idea since this is matter of taste...

Comment: a limit of 300 is far of industry standard, who has set that limit? You self? Then the value of 300 is a bad idea, too. Have you ever thoght why newspapers have multiple columns whil ebooks don't have? Once you find out, you will know why 300 is not a good idea. And if you work in a company a value of 300 should somebody make his alarm bells ringing. consider refactoring your code, maybe it is too nested.